# Ionic 3 unable to reject promise in a callback function

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, ionic3

I wrote a function in Ionic 3 to get user's location and get its address using user's longitude and latitude. This function also check if user's location settings is enabled, if no, it will call `this.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings()` it basically show location setting for user to switch on. I also added `this.diagnostic.registerLocationStateChangeHandler` method to check if user actually switch on location in location setting that I show previously. If everything is okay I will continue run other processes such as getting Geolocation and translate to address.

Below is my complete code:

```
  getMyLocation() {
    this.geoOptions = {
      enableHighAccuracy: false
    }
    const loadingMsg = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Getting your location..."
    })

    loadingMsg.present();



    this.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled().then(test => {
        this.diagnostic.registerLocationStateChangeHandler((state)=>{
        if((this.platform.is('ios')) && (state !== this.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED ||
           state !== this.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED_WHEN_IN_USE) ||
           (this.platform.is('android')) && (state === this.diagnostic.locationMode.LOCATION_OFF )){
            return Promise.reject("Please switch on your location");
          }
       })
      if (!test) {
        this.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings()
      }

      // return this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.geoOptions)
      return this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.geoOptions)
      // console.log("Error! Please switch on your location");
      // return Promise.reject("Error! Please switch on your location");
    },(err:any)=>{
      loadingMsg.dismiss();
      console.log("error : " + err);

    }).then((pos: Geoposition) =>{

      return this.nativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);

    },(err: PositionError)=>{
      loadingMsg.dismiss();
      console.log("error : " + err.message);
      return Promise.reject(err.message);

    }).then((result: NativeGeocoderReverseResult) =>{

      this.currentAddress = result.locality+", "+result.countryName;
      loadingMsg.dismiss();

    },(err:any)=>{

      console.log("error : " + err);
      loadingMsg.dismiss();
      return Promise.reject(err);

    })
  }
```

The problem is I am unable to stop promise chaining if user did not switch on after `this.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings()` is fired. The place where I tried to stop the chaining is within `this.diagnostic.registerLocationStateChangeHandler` callback function. I am a beginner to promise chaining method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

**i.e.** You can use `throw new Error('abort promise chain');return null;` at the place where you need to `abort promise chain`.

```
 this.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled().then(test => {
        this.diagnostic.registerLocationStateChangeHandler((state)=>{
        if((this.platform.is('ios')) && (state !== this.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED ||
           state !== this.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED_WHEN_IN_USE) ||
           (this.platform.is('android')) && (state === this.diagnostic.locationMode.LOCATION_OFF )){
            throw new Error('abort promise chain');//here
            return null;
          }
       })
```

Comment: Thanks!, i manage to get it work now, although there are several problems i found in my code... so for simplicity i removed `this.diagnostic.registerLocationStateChangeHandler` and i added `throw new Error('abort promise chain');` into `if(!test)` statement. Then i found out, if there is an error in my promise chain, i don't have to create error handlers for all the `then(success,err)` instead i just create it at the last chain  or put `.catch(err)` to it.

Comment: OK Great! Here you can find out more options: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/581

Comment: I see there are more way to handle promises using bluebird thanks!